# Are there any standard android attribute which specifies color of text to be white

Tags: android

Can you please tell me if there is any standard android textColor which specifies the color of the text to be white?

I have tried either textColorPrimary or textColorSecondary, but both are black.

```
<Button
 android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary
/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or `android:textColor="@android:color/white"`

Answer (score 2):

What about: `android:textColor="#ffffffff"`?

or Cristian's `android:textColor="@android:color/white"`.

Other colors you can use are listed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html#background_dark).

Comment: Really? I thought I did this all the time.